# Should all applicable tags be used?

Tags: discussion, tags

I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440846/how-do-i-listen-for-children-visibility-change) a framework specific question and it was language-tagged later by somebody.

Does it make sense to add wider tag when question is already described by more specific ones?

Should we include language tag anywhere where language can be recognized?

Comment: Yes, you _must_ use the language tag. Tags help experts find a question, i.e. only questions having their prefered tags are visible to them. In your case, you missed Java and added all other tags which experts may not follow. So your question will not appear in their customized front page and rss feed, effectively hiding your questions from experts. Java tag is the proper tag for your question if you want the java answerers to see your post.

Comment: But I want framework users to answer, not Java developers.

Comment: @Basilevs: It is not up to you as to who answers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It up to me to make question as searchable as possible. And adding unnecessary tags makes it worse.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if the question contains code in a given language you should add that language as tag (this also makes the syntax highlighter use the correct rules). If you expect an answer to contain code in a language you should add that language too. There *could* be questions that are framework related but don't require the language tag. For example questions about configuration of the framework, or about changes in its API/implementation. But these questions should *not* be about programming with the framework.

Comment: @Basilevs - Another reason: I think language tagging is also important for syntax highlighting. Unless you do something like [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). Highlighting give the question a more polished look.

Comment: @Basilevs: How does [tag:java] make your question _less_ searchable? That's ridiculous. Yesterday your argument was that doing so would make _other_ questions (language-specific ones) less searchable, which is at least a logical concern. This new argument makes no sense at all.

Comment: @jww one can manually set up the syntax highlighting using `<!--- language: lang-java --->` or whatever you need, that isn't reason enough to add tags.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I often find myself ignoring reading java tagged questions as they are usually about syntax errors, collections, "give me the code", an other things I'm not interested in. I therefore would like to avoid using this overloaded tag, which might even hit ignore lists in order to make my tagging as specific as possible.

Comment: @Basilevs: That's a wider problem with SO but I don't think your solution is the right one, even though it may give you personally a short-term benefit. You're just creating a wider problem of mistagged questions.

Comment: @Basilevs - my bad. I was not aware you were already adding the language tags for the syntax highlighting. I think  Infinite Recursion provided the primary reason for adding proper language tags. Syntax highlighting is just an additional benefit.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, IMHO, a lot of Java tagged questions are mistagged. Here are some questionable ones from the first page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686825/how-to-remove-unused-imports-from-eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465334/udp-hole-punching-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096420/maven-reference-for-springframework-org-tags-form-per-spring-source-ide I'm not creating a problem, I'm solving one.

Comment: @Basilevs: I would tend to agree that those as mistagged, yes. Still doesn't mean _you_ are okay to mistag, making the problem _worse_. If we had tag heirarchies then it would be possible to search for "Java questions with at least one sub-tag present" and your problem would be solved; but we do not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But I don't mistag. I just make a proper tagging, without irrelevant tags.

Comment: @Basilevs: You are asking a question about Java code (even if Java code that you did not write). Therefore, [tag:java] is _not_ "irrelevant tags". I don't know how else to say this to you that will be clearer. _Include the [tag:java] tag._

Comment: People tag Joomla with PHP or SQL all the time and get wrong answers as a result. Sometimes they get inappropriate close votes or told they are idiots because the question is a good Joomla question but a bad PHP or  SQL question. For example frameworks solve a lot of problems with SQL injection or XSS, but if you don't know the framework you have no idea. If it is really a question about the use of the framework, I wouldn't tag it with the language. Of course, oftem OP doesn't know. The question needs a new title and introduction to indicate that he only wants an answer in the context of SWT.

Comment: @Elin: It really depends. People who are using Joomla's front-end _only_ should not be tagging [tag:php], because they are not writing any PHP: they are just using a graphical interface. However, AFAICT the OP here is talking about _programming_ in a Java framework. As such, the [tag:java] tag is appropriate.

Comment: People who are using front end only should not be posting on SO. I'm talking about programming in PHP using the Joomla framework.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194182/how-to-ensure-that-questions-get-super-tags

Answer (score 13):

The rules are a bit simpler than you're trying to make them. Try this:

Is the code in the question written in Java? Do you want an *answer* written in Java? Use the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag!

There is a limit of 5 tags. It doesn't hurt to use all 5 that you are allowed to use, as long as they are appropriate for the question. Tags are how experts find questions to answer and how we categorize questions. Don't be overly pedantic or philosophical about it. The Java libraries are still related to Java.

Comment: Won't this make other questions which are truly related to language less searchable?

Comment: @Basilevs: Well, there's [tag:language-lawyer] and [tag:standard] and so forth, but you're right. Still, it's the better of two evils.

Answer (score 3):

The rule of thumb is that you should put the programming language that relates to your question. In the case of your specific question, I would have put [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) among the tags.

However, in general, there exist *some* exceptions where adding a language-specific tag can drive away people who *could* answer your question. Here's one example. Selenium is a project that has produced libraries that allow you to drive web browsers. So you can write code that will open a web page, find a link, click on it, etc. and it will be able to control Firefox, Chrome, IE, whatever... These libraries exist in multiple languages: Java, Python, C#, Ruby, JavaScript, etc. The fact is that the **vast majority** of Selenium questions posted on SO are about problems that belong to Selenium proper, irrespective of the language that one uses. And since the API is quite regular from language to language, it is easy for someone who has never programmed in a given language (but who is *not* a novice at software languages in general) to still understand questions or answers written in that language. I have answered Selenium questions in languages I've never used.

So in a case like this, an OP who does not care what language is used to answer the question could skip the language-specific tag so as to avoid driving away people who do not know *that* specific language but could *otherwise* answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

(Cody Gray mentions this, but only in passing.)

Absolutely. Users filter the questions they see by tags. By apply a broader language tag, you expose your questions to those users. By tagging it with a particular language, framework, or concept, you're attracting someone who knows a lot about those subjects and is likely to have an answer to your question.

Almost all questions should have a language tag. (If not, think hard about whether it would be better suited to another site like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.) With some languages/tools, you can go a step further: tag with both the language/tool tag and the version specific tag. (I've had people edit my post to do that before.) This gets your question into potential answerer's lists and it tells everyone what version you're using immediately. Only use the version specific tag if it's important, though (like in Python where the way certain features work is very different in some versions).

So the main question with tagging is, "Who do I want to see my question? What should they know a lot about?" Any tags that indicate the knowledge required to answer the question should be added.

Comment: Meh, be careful with version-specific tags. See [the guidelines here on the über-Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/what-are-the-guidelines-for-using-version-specific-tags).

Comment: @CodyGray Suppose I've been living in the Python world too long, then.

Answer (score 1):

> Should all applicable tags be used?

This is the *real* rule of thumb:

To add tags, you should ask yourself: is my question about [tag]?

- If the answer is "no", then you shouldn't,
- if the answer is "yes" the you should,
- if the answer is "maybe, I don't know" then you can throw a coin to the air to decide, but probably you should check related tags to the ones you applied, and don't feel bad if someone removes them later.