# Feedback requested: New “recommended” homepage, phase 2

Tags: discussion, question-quality, homepage, se-quality-project

A while ago, we started work on a new homepage algorithm for Stack Overflow.

[See phase 1 (with feedback)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261138/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-1), and [motivations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so) for some more detail.

We had gotten to a point where **we were pretty happy with the unanswered questions** in that algorithm, but the "interesting answered questions" weren't cutting it.  Phase 2 is a new whack at that problem.

We're now **mixing in a few explicitly interesting questions** on https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=recent. I'd like some feedback on how we're doing.

You can tell a question has been denoted as "interesting" for you, because the question is a) answered, b) the answer has a score > 0, and c) the question has a score > 0.

Here's how it's working* now:

1. Filter to recent quality questions

   - Answered (has an answer with score > 0)
   - Upvoted (effectively, score > 0)
2. For each post, calculate how much of an outlier it is in the following metrics

   - Question score / age
   - Question score / length
   - Question score / views
   - ... and then the same three again, except for the answer
3. Weight that outlier-ness by your tag preferences (explicit or inferred).
4. Randomly choose from the weighted set of questions and mix them in.

A benefit of this approach is that it "tunes" to how active Stack Overflow is at that time.

---

Some examples of questions this algorithm has chosen for me (a mostly-C# developer) since it went live earlier today:

#### [Why is a nested struct inside a generic class considered "managed"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25482156/why-is-a-nested-struct-inside-a-generic-class-considered-managed)

#### [Boolean array initialization in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25470241/boolean-array-initialization-in-c)

#### [What namespace will a class have if no namespace is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491518/c-sharp-what-namespace-will-a-class-have-if-no-namespace-is-defined)

#### [Entity FrameWork CodeFirst using context in Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477652/entity-framework-codefirst-using-context-in-controller)

#### [Efficient BigInteger multiplication modulo n in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484616/efficient-biginteger-multiplication-modulo-n-in-java)

---

What is doing a good job for *me* (who mostly designed the algorithm) is basically the low bar. Now it's time to get some feedback. So, what do you think?

<sub>*Simplifying by omitting a lot of normalization here.</sub>

Comment: Maybe I've got too many varied 'favorite' tags, but the 'interesting' questions it chose for me aren't particularly interesting. I do Java mainly, plus some Rails, but the 'interesting' questions suggested for me are about specific Java and Rails libraries I have no interest in. Maybe a side effect of questions being tagged with both the library/add-on and the parent language?

Comment: You can see even more of what the new algorithm thinks is "interesting" on the hot subtab: http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=hot

Comment: I like this: it emphasizes questions that aren't *so good* that they already have 1 or 2 great answers, but it also throws away the *terrible* questions that I'm so accustomed to seeing: nice job. The only gripe I have is that it's showing a lot of questions in tags that I've never even touched. I'm mostly active in JavaScript, iOS, Swift, and Java, but I'm getting lots of C, C++, C#, etc. questions.

Comment: I'm seeing questions with answers after selecting "Needs Answer". Can questions with multiple favorite tags be weighted heavier?

Comment: I don't have time for extensive tests, but looking at its results for few refreshes it seems to be doing fine job, well done!

Comment: @Mooseman I think "needs answer" uses the same definition as "unanswered:" no *upvoted* answers.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas welcome to the club http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269589/792066

Comment: Same complaint as @AstroCB. I'm getting iOS questions... and I'm an Android developer. I've only touched iOS questions for edits and closing, so why would it recommend them to me?

Comment: I am C++ developer, but I have Java and some other tags (total: c++, java, c, c++11, turbojpeg, c++14) in my favorites too, somehow I don't understand why I get so many android tagged questions (ok, often in relation with java, but I am not interested in android at all!), along with [that one for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492473/vs2013-how-to-pass-the-solution-folder-solutiondir-in-the-command-line-ar) (never touched C# and didn't work on Windows for a while now) Edit: maybe add a "hate-list"? ;)

Comment: @hichris123: So you can edit and close them, duh.

Comment: It is a big, *big* improvement over the first version.  The only flaw I see is that it doesn't consistently apply the ignored tags in my preferences, but that doesn't go wrong very often.  Let it rip!

Comment: Opposite complaint to @AstroCB; I'm seeing nothing that isn't on my favourites... Which means I'm not going to see anything interesting unless it hits the hot questions list... How is the weighting done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=recent is still pretty much useless for me, I suspect because I never bothered cleaning my "favorite tags" list. In 6 years, I never worked with the homepage... I primarily look for answer in certains tags, with *no* answer yet.

Comment: I get some of your questions too :) (Why is a nested struct inside a generic class considered “managed”?, What namespace will a class have if no namespace is defined) plus some other interesting C# questions, some JS, some Scala. Fairly representative of my interests! I appreciate there are a couple of questions from tags I never touched (haskell, dart). They are interesting to read, so.. why not?

Comment: Only one point: they seem quite "new". I have nothing older than 22hrs ago. Is that intentional?

Comment: Mixed bag for me. I have a bunch of good Rails/git/JS/redirecting questions, which seems to be where I spend the most time. But mixed in are some Java/Android/C++/WTF questions, maybe 1 in 3. (To @LorenzoDematté's point, most are newish but some haven't been touched for months.) I do get a bunch of questions which need moderation attention, though (e.g. "That's not an answer...") which is probably good.

Comment: @LorenzoDematté it tunes to how active Stack Overflow is at that time, it does *prefer* new content but there's no explicit time window.

Comment: @BoltClock */me goes to close all iOS questions*

Comment: @KevinMontrose: I answer questions for one tag and it's also my one favorite tag. For the "interesting" tab, I get a few questions displayed for this tag and the rest of the displayed questions are for random, uninteresting tags. The "interesting" classification scheme doesn't work for me. For example, the first question displayed: [Mismatch between jmeter jmx file created from code and from jmeter gui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511949/mismatch-between-jmeter-jmx-file-created-from-code-and-from-jmeter-gui). Why would I ever be interested in this?

Comment: I always ignore whats in the home page as it does not provide detail to the question. I choose one of the tag which I'm more proficient at. May be you can track the user behavior and show that to him. some kind of AI at your end.

Comment: re:[hot] Most results are for tags that aren't in my favourites, but do exclude Ignored tags, I would prefer greater concentration on the favourites (perhaps the sorting?)

Comment: Clearly going against the trend, but it's immediately useful for me. I've straight away found some questions I can contribute to that match my regular field of expertise. Look forward to the full release.

Comment: You say score > 0… I'm seeing -2 and -3 questions…

Comment: Why rely on subjective human feedback when you can A/B test (in addition)?

Comment: I thought it was pretty good, I saw some questions that interested me outside of what I would normally read/answer, and I even answered one that I knew about the general issue but not the specific framework.

Comment: Is there any recent update to the algorithm? Previously I had same complaint as AstroCB regarding "mixed bag" of questions. But when I tested again just now (favorite tag: only Android), mostly I got Java questions with 1 question for the rest of the tags. Seems improvement for me... or is it just a coincidence? ._.

Comment: The list for me shows lots of unanswered questions *and* questions with aggregate negative scores (36, to be exact). It even includes a question with both a score of -2 and no answers.

Answer (score 32):

I've given it a few days now, but my impression is that, for me, the new page doesn't work as well as the previous algorithm.  Since the change has been made, I've seen fewer questions that I'm actually interested in looking at, much less answering.  For me, going back to the previous algorithm, would be better.  It could be coincidence; there are such dips periodically.  But I think the mix of questions I'm seeing is different, but nowhere near as interesting.

This is one of those things where it is very hard to compare — it is extremely subjective because there isn't a page with the old algorithm at work and another with the new algorithm at work, so I have to work off remembered impressions of ephemeral behaviour (you don't usually get the same page twice anyway).  If you want accurate benchmarking, you should consider having both algorithms available in parallel.  Then people can choose which they prefer — and you'll know which is preferable.

Comment: This could be because of the fall term starting though as well. Of the recent 200 newest questions, none of them have more than 1 upvote.

Comment: Actually this is a good idea - make a page which would have two columns of questions so we see the new and the old algorithm side by side. It will be little ugly on narrow screens, but it is just for testing, so it does not matter.

Comment: I think this would indeed be the only way to really get a grip on which is preferable.

Comment: @gorn - I think that's a great suggestion! It could be de-uglied using tabs / buttons to select content in the same limited space we have now.