# "Show n more comments" usability problem

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-experience

When there is a long discussion, the "Show *n* more comments" link is only shown at the bottom.  This is a problem.

When there is a significant amount of discussion, only comments with upvotes are shown in the list, and often, the comments they are in reply to have lower scores, and are only visible behind the "Show *n* more comments" link.

Example: [Feedback requested: New “recommended” homepage, phase 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269769/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-2?cb=1)

If you decide you want to read the entire discussion, the previously hidden comments are exposed.  There is no indication which ones you have (possibly) already seen. You can try to guess from the upvotes, but this is apparently not always entirely predictable.

A typical failure scenario is that you start reading comments, scroll down for a bit, read some more, scroll down for a bit, realize fully only then that you have seen only a partial list, click to show all the comments, and start over from the top, browsing for comments which you have not already read, often missing a few, or getting mixed up about where you were.

I'm not sure how this could be improved. One semi-obvious suggestion would be to have the "Show *n* more comments" at the top of the list of comments, instead of at the bottom.

Comment: I don't think the order of the comments changes when you expand, does it? It's just that the previously omitted comments are inserted into the sequence. The order of the ones you already saw remains the same, as far as I can tell. Still, I agree that it's not a good user experience. I have gotten into a habit of looking for an expand link at the bottom before I start reading long comment threads. Having it at the top would be a clear improvement, and sounds like a simple change.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Thanks for the hidden vs shuffled comment; question edited (also included an example).

Comment: @EugenePodskal While your ideology is correct, experience here on Meta is that there are scenarios where long comment threads are regular, expected, and inevitable.

Comment: @tripleee I do not say that I am against it. In fact for Meta discussions it is a desired improvement of UX. But for [SO] it isn't very useful - comment threads usually are either detective stories, that aren't of much use(at least if OP edits its question), or too short and not coherent to be of use as whole.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235259/163863 for a great solution to this problem. Unfortunately, it has been shot down by SE as being too technically challenging. Lameeeeeeee.

Comment: It is a shame that the placeholders idea was shot down as being expensive, though I suppose I understand that. But the much less costly step of tagging new comments with an extra css class that gives them a slightly different background color would improve the ability to skim for/around them dramatically.

Comment: @Matt Uhhh, it would not be difficult to move more of the algorithm into the javascript and download all comments on initial load...  I mean, I'm sure that could even be done as a userscript!  (Unless they're referring to extra load on the servers for requesting all comments on every page, perhaps?  That's definitely not what Laura's comment over there sounds like, though)

Comment: I think we should just hide all comments by default and have an option to click "show comments" and view all comments. That's how many sites do it and it works fine; people who care about comments tend to read them all.

Comment: @TylerH - It seems to me that your suggestion makes more sense for answers than it does for questions. Comments on questions often point out issues with the question itself and I think at least the start of them should be shown by default. Personally, I'd rather see the comments simply chopped off after the first _n_ (with a button to show more). I don't find that the current strategy particularly enhances usable.

Comment: I have heard them say that they do not care about comments and have intentionally made them not so user friendly because they want people to focus on the answers not comments. In the end, we do not matter too much. It is all about the bottom line. Are improving the UX of comments going to increase the bottom line?

Comment: @true All improvements to the site can be argued to increase the bottom line, depending on your perspective and definitions of "increase" and "bottom line."

Comment: @TylerH increase the bottom line means exactly that. interpret it as a literal statement -  [_the bottom line_](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=bottom+line+defintion)

Comment: @true Not sure if you are under- or overestimating your audience. Do you have a particular point that you want to make, or are you griping about the status quo?

Answer (score 4):

#### One semi-obvious suggestion would be to have the "Show n more comments" at the top of the list of comments, instead of at the bottom.

You should take a look at [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox).

Just one of the many optional features it adds is "Move 'show x more comments' to the top":

[image]

> **Requirements**
>
> Install Greasemonkey (for Firefox), Tampermonkey (for Chrome), or
>   NinjaKit for Safari. These are userscript managers that must be
>   installed in order for this to work, as the script relies on certain
>   GM_* functions in order to save your settings!

Comment: This is super useful. I still wish it would be part of the standard layout without having to use a plugin though. After all, the idea was already [quite highly upvoted on Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24490/can-we-get-an-indication-comments-are-hidden-between-the-comments). For some reason Jeff didn't like it, I'm not sure why.