# Bringing attention to old meta questions (when you can't edit)

Tags: discussion

**tl;dr** How can I bring attention to old posts that I can neither edit nor offer a bounty on?

Enter the rabbit hole.

Halfway through reading the (visible) comments on [What is Stack Overflow's Goal?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal) it occurred to me that the list was getting long enough that there was probably going to be a *show* ***##*** *more comments* link at the bottom. Sure enough, there are 44 more comments at the time of this writing.

When I click on it, as I often find, the previously hidden comments are scattered throughout the original comments I'd already read. I'm not sure how the engine decides what to hide and what to keep. It appears to be some combination of upvotes and maintaining back and forth conversations between specific @users. Either way, the highlighting on the newly displayed comments is rapidly fading away and I just have to guess which ones I haven't already read, or (more frequently) just start all over again from the top down.

Anyway, I think to myself *gee, wouldn't it be more helpful if this "show more comments" link was at the* ***top*** *of the comments section instead of the bottom?* If it were, I could decide (based on the quality of the question/answer) whether I want to read the full discussion or just the highlights. Whereas at present I'm seeing the highlights only, and then have to **go back** to see the full discussion, if I come across that link at the bottom.

Alternatively, if it only hid the most recent comments, it could still be at the bottom, as I would be able to easily see the break point between what I've already read and what was just uncovered.

So, next thought, *maybe someone already asked this?* Oh look, someone did ask [“Show *n* more comments” usability problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270396/show-n-more-comments-usability-problem) ... but that question is old, and it was briefly discussed, but received no answers. Hmm, I wonder what I could do to bring it back into focus? Offer a bounty? [Nope](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265798/bounties-on-meta-questions). I guess I'll have to ask/search for a question about *that*.

Ok, found a question [On Meta, how do you get attention for questions without an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266782/on-meta-how-do-you-get-attention-for-questions-without-an-answer) **and** it even has an answer: edit the question.

I'm not super excited about editing the question, but I guess I can append my alternative suggestion of hide the most recent comments instead of moving the link to the top. Off we go...

[image]

**Nnnrrrrghh!**

Now what?

I mean, obviously the question I'm asking right now has itself brought attention to the issue / feature-request I wanted to discuss. But it is titled and tagged incorrectly for that purpose. And if I post the question separately, it is just a duplicate of the one I already linked in here. So what is the "correct" thing to do?

Comment: See my answer ["Show n more comments" usability problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317724) which has also bumped that question for you ;)

Comment: Regarding comments, I always scroll to the end of the list first to see if there is that link, then click it and scroll back to the top. But having that at the top would be great.

Answer (score 19):

A very useful option is to answer, if you have a valid answer to the question. In the specific example you present, you mention you have an alternative suggestion. You can post that as an answer, which will bump the post in the "active" tab. (This has the bonus side-effect of *not* putting a suggestion in the OP's mouth.)

Aside from that, you *could* open a new question and admit it's a duplicate. I don't advise this, however, as knowingly asking a duplicate might net you some heat from other users.

A third option would be bringing it up in chat. You can just ask if anyone has thoughts on the matter, or if someone could bump it with an edit. Be warned that not all chat rooms may be okay with this. If you can, try to check through any rules they have posted and make sure you won't be causing a problem, for yourself or them.

Comment: Well that would be the [blindingly obvious](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/59998) solution I totally missed. Hahaha!

Comment: I've found the best solutions are the ones that I overlook twenty times and want to kick myself for missing when someone points them out. :)

Comment: @JoeMalpass Fourth option: change your username to [Move more comments link to top](http://stackoverflow.com/users/152094/move-more-comments-link-to-top).

Comment: @Sally I somehow don`t see the fourth option as being any helpful though :P

Comment: @Sally Lol. See my answer ;)

Comment: @Patrice I bet it could be helpful if you also then make an active effort to answer questions/ask good questions of your own. Unfortunately, that user asked three questions, then left and hasn't been seen in almost half a year. :/