# Recommended tab timing out with HTTP 500

Tags: bug, recommended-tab

I get an HTTP 500 with one of [these](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/error-cats/361437458.jpg) [pictures](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/error-cats/365705759.jpg) when attempting to load the [recommended tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended).

I get the same error after several seconds whether I am logged in or not. Is the recommended tab gone for good, or is the HTTP 500 temporary?

Comment: Related for those who don't know what the recommended tab is: [Feedback requested: New “recommended” homepage, phase 2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269769/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be working without error now.