# What's the difference between questions link and stackoverflow link

Tags: support, questions, homepage

What exactly is the difference between https://stackoverflow.com/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions links.

I just noticed the Stack Overflow logo was a link but it seems to bring up a different question list compared to questions link. What's the difference between them? One page has the latest and the other filtered questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are different pages. One is the homepage presented to the 'general public' with a selection of posts, the other a complete questions list for all tags.

You can filter the latter to a specific tag, by adding `/tagged/<tagname>` after it, and / or can be reordered by age, votes or activity, and filtered to only unanswered or bountied posts.

The homepage makes a selection of ['interesting' posts](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/), it is not an exhaustive list. Stack Exchange is in the process of making the page more interesting by tailoring it to your preferences and interests, see:

- [The Stack Overflow homepage is over-emphasizing bad questions (and a proposed solution)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so)
- [Feedback requested: New "recommended" homepage, phase 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261138/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-1)
- [Feedback requested: New “recommended” homepage, phase 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269769/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-2)
- [Feedback requested: New "recommended" homepage, phase 3 - algorithm tweaks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271128/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-algorithm-phase-3)

Comment: Why do they bring up a different list though?

Comment: After your update, homepage gives interesting questions and the `/questions` list is the latest, is that correct?

Comment: @artm: the questions list is the 'complete' view (ordered by newest or active, or filtered to everything with a bounty or filtered to not being answered).