# How is the interesting tab on the front page of Stack Overflow populated?

Tags: support, front-page, interesting-page

What is the algorithm that determines what questions appear on the "interesting" tab of Stack Overflow?

Comment: I really want to know! Why downvote me!

Comment: Hover your mouse over the downvote arrow, the reason for downvotes is displayed in the tooltip.

Comment: I saw it ,but I don't agree with it so I modified my question!

Comment: Are you explicitly looking at the recommended tab for this?

Comment: @Snowwhite are you asking about the box called  "Questions that may already have your answer" that appears when you actually typing a question?  Or the box in the side bar with "Related Questions"?  OR do you mean the front page of the site with a list of "interesting" questions?

Comment: @Snowwhite Now that we know what you are asking, I have rewritten your question to make it clear.

Comment: @Snow, now that the question is clear, you may be interested in reading [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138382/164403) on the Overmeta. Keep in mind [things are changing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271128/464709), though.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest answer to your question is found in [Why do some recently asked questions not show up in the question list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138366/why-do-some-recently-asked-questions-not-show-up-in-the-question-list) in which [Shadow Wizard's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) accepted answer quotes from Jeff Atwood's blog post [Stack Overflow Homepage Changes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/)

> Here’s how it works. Starting with a list of the last 3,000 active
> questions:
>
> - drop questions containing any of your ignored tags
> - drop closed questions if you lack the reputation required to vote for reopening
> - drop questions scoring -4 or lower
>
> Next, apply the following score formula to the remaining questions:
>
> your [interesting tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/expressing-your-tag-preferences/)
>             
> +1,500 per interesting tag, up to +2,000 total
>
> your top 40 scoring tags       maximum of
> +1,000 per tag (scaled), up to +2,000 total
>
> question score
>                     
> +200 × score, up to +1,000 total
>
> total answer score
>                
> -200 × score, up to -1,000 total
>
> number of answers
>              
> -200 × answers, up to -1,000 total
>
> number of views
>                   
> -15 × views, up to -1,000 total
>
> question last activity date       -1 ×
> (seconds / 15)
>
> Count it all up and take the top 90 by score.

However, as [Frederic Hamidi mentions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281708/how-is-the-interesting-tab-on-the-front-page-of-stack-overflow-populated#comment137069_281708), there are plans in place to replace that with a different algorithm to help highlight good quality content.  You can see some of the existing discussion in:

- [Feedback requested: New "recommended" homepage, phase 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261138/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-1)
- [Feedback requested: New “recommended” homepage, phase 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269769/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-2)
- [Feedback requested: New "recommended" homepage, phase 3 - algorithm tweaks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271128/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-3-algorithm-tweaks)

Comment: For anyone who is interested about the "new recommend homepage": phase 4 is here --> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276840/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-4-filters