# Is there a way to see only questions from users above a certain level?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I have read quite a few poor questions from users with a very low rank (let's say below 20 or so) and the problems with these questions were always the same. Be it, the users have not searched themselves, be it I could not understand what they were talking about (though I am not a native speaker, I think I can follow/understand most of the questions asked here).

Giving the same suggestions ("Please post an MWE.", "Have you done this or that?", "Did you read the manual?" and so on) is boring the pants off me, so I was wondering if you can limit the displayed questions to users above a certain level (say, 50 or so)?

Comment: If most users apply your filter mentioned, when will the questions from newbies be answered?

Comment: You are right but that was not the question, was it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=recent&minRep=50

Comment: @amuse Never, and maybe that's a good thing.

Comment: People have asked for the same feature for people with rep levels higher then what you have, so a feature like that could have prevented you from getting the help you needed.

Comment: What if we apply that same filter, but make it so it's questions from users with more than 1000 rep. How would you get answers to your questions? And if no one ever saw your questions, how would you ever get above 1000 rep so you *could* be seen? You seem to be forgetting the entire spirit and purpose of SO, which is to collect knowledge; that knowledge can originate from (or be shared by) anyone, including those who haven't amassed a bunch of rep here (yet) like you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is not an option in the [advanced search options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

However, if you're looking to avoid low quality questions you could use the existing search options to:

- Filter out questions newer than 3 days old. This way you're skipping any questions that would get deleted immediately.
- Filter out questions with a notice. This way you're skipping any questions that got put on hold, were closed, or marked as duplicates. (NOTE: I believe this also filters out protected questions.)
- Filter out questions with a score less than 1.

This won't guarantee that you don't see low quality questions but it should help.

Comment: [Or there's this page](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=recent&minRep=50) at least until it's removed when new-nav comes out, or that code path is abandoned.

Comment: @theB - 'minRep' doesn't appear to actually change anything.

Comment: The filter is only applied to the asker's reputation, so if there's a suggested edit, or an answer from a lower reputation user, the last modified label may have a lower reputation than the filter.  Also the thing was built as a [demo](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269769/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-2) so there are probably edge cases that aren't covered, and its subject to change. (Either way, I still think that there's a false equivalence between asker's reputation and question quality.)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, that *would not be fair*. Someone else would have to do the work of reading, understanding, then upvote/downvote questions so that those questions/users appear in your page.  We all want to see good questions. If everyone looks only at questions from users with >50 rep, how would a relatively new user will get any answers?

Also, your definition of low quality asker (rep<50) is weak. What if an user has 40 reputation with only a single question and no answers? That means that user has already a question with 8 upvotes!

Third, a user might be really bad at asking questions in a certain tag but really good at asking questions in another one.

Besides, you always can filter the questions you choose to answer. If a user has 3 rep with 15 questions, just skip the question.

Comment: I've edited your post for grammar.  Please feel free to [edit] it some more, especially if I misinterpreted any part of your answer.

Comment: @ryanyuyu thanks, it's ok. I am also a grammar nazi for romanian, but I am very poor at english.