# Should all Django questions get a Python tag too?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

So [this user is hammering the Django section with edit suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/612124/mohsen?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) to add the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag to any questions that omit it. There are *also* some valid suggestions, but the focus of this effort seems to be to add [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) to all the things.

The [question of mine edited today](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9286520) is about the Django command-line tools, it's not even about Python.

Does every framework need tagging in its language too? And if not, can a mod have a word?

Comment: If the framework has a life outside of the language itself, or the question isn't asking a question about something to do with implementing part of the framework, then the language tag doesn't apply.

Comment: This discussion has been made with regards to whether all ruby on rails questions should be tagged with ruby.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41206/should-questions-be-tagged-with-both-a-tag-and-a-sub-tag || http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165003/should-posts-be-tagged-as-both-android-and-java?rq=1 || http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171585/when-not-to-use-a-tag-that-is-inherently-applicable?lq=1

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269589/should-all-applicable-tags-be-used

Answer (score 64):

> Does every framework need tagging in its language too?

Not all frameworks deal with a single language, so not all questions tagged with a specific framework should also be tagged with a single language.

> Should all Django questions get a Python tag too?

No. Not all Django questions involve Python (like Django templates, URL configuration, etc.), and most of the time **the question can't be answered by the Python community at large**.

This is especially true for frameworks with large communities, such as Django, as they don't need the language tag to increase the visibility of the question.

> But what about small frameworks?

*(You didn't ask this, but someone is thinking about it)*

Tags on Stack Overflow serve a few purposes, one of them is to categorize questions. Another is to determine who is more likely to see the question, someone following [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) is more likely to see a Python question than a [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) person, *and that's a good thing*. So by tagging a question about a not-as-widely-used framework with a language tag (assuming it's relevant) will greatly increase the exposure of the question and increase the chance of it getting a relevant response.

> Should these edits be accepted?

For the most part, these edits are adding tags that are *somewhat relevant* to the question, which is normally a Good Thing™. But most of these tags are [not going to help](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9286447) in searching for the question in the future or are [actually not relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9286494), and that's a Bad Thing™.

Comment: `the Python community at large`: that makes me think of a lot of snakes who were living together in captivity, then escaped.

Comment: @BillWoodger [Snakes on a Plane](http://snakeplay.pbworks.com/f/fake_poster.jpg)?

Comment: @durron597 That's a film I've got to see, thankssss :-)

Comment: @durron597 I'm so tired of these ***** snakes on this ********* plane!!!

Comment: @BillWoodger So if the Django community escaped, would that be Django Unchained? :P

Comment: @BillWoodger I love how your comment has exactly the same amount of up votes as the answer

Comment: Did we ever let the user know about this discussion? [He's still doing that](http://stackoverflow.com/users/612124/mohsen?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Comment: @approxiblue _sigh_... yes. And they took a "break" shortly after my flag was marked "helpful" the first time.