# Bold text in the wrong place in Marked As Duplicate!

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, design

Today I came across a question that has been marked as duplicate and the message shows like this:

[image]

I found this very strange. I thought the bold text would be "**duplicate**", not "**marked**". That just seems wrong. **Or maybe make the whole sentence bold**.

I guess the cause of this is that every other message's bold text is at the beginning of it. e.g. **put on hold**, **closed**, **protected** and **locked**. So maybe the developers thought "ok, let's just apply bold to the first span" or something.

My own CSS knowledge cannot tell me how they did this, or is it intentional?

Comment: If it was just the first word, one of the other reasons would read "**put** on hold". I suggest the entire phrase to be bolded: "**marked as duplicate** by .." as that is the quintessential part of the message.

Comment: @Jongware: There's two parts. The first is the *verb* (put on hold, closed, marked) and the second is the *reason* (opinion, off-topic, duplicate, etc). Only the verb is bolded, and changing that would require a wee bit more tweaking than a casual glance would suggest.

Comment: Worth noting that on the mobile site, "marked as duplicate by" is _all_ bold.

Comment: **Is** this a **case** of alternative **title case** in which certain **words** are bolded but others **aren't**?

Comment: Am I the only one concerned more with the hovercraft full of eels?

Comment: @canon they are not eels really, they are disguised snakes, during their escape: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303459/should-all-django-questions-get-a-python-tag-too#comment238469_303462. I should consider deleting the original comment, as *the Python community at large* turns out to be a real recognised phrase :-)