# Is tagging library dependency appropriate when it is not the focus of the question?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm wondering if there is a consensus on whether or not it is appropriate to add tags that are library dependencies of the library that is central to a question.

For example, I see a number of [theano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/theano)-tagged questions make improper use of the [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) tag. In many of [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/theano+numpy), the question is not about numpy syntax, but it just happens that theano has numpy as a dependency, and there is numpy code used to setup some of the code examples.

The opposite is also true, where users are trying to accomplish something in theano, but are having an issue that is purely related to numpy. In this case, the minimum working example should include only numpy-related code, and the theano tag dropped.

Another place where this is often seen is in bounty questions, which frequently involve installing/using a new/small-user-base library that depends on a mainstream library, but where the larger library is not the focus of the question.

Should all the elements included in the question/code be tagged regardless of the focus of the question? Is it OK to remove tags that are not central to the question being asked?

Comment: [Related question about adding the Python tag to Django (a Python framework) questions.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303459/359284)

Comment: If there is NumPy code in the question and even if the focus is only marginally on that code, I might still add the tag. It depends. Focus of question is kind of non-binary concept there. Things can be more in focus or less in focus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should all the elements included in the question/code be tagged regardless of the focus of the question?

No.

> Is it OK to remove tags that are not central to the question being asked?

Sure it is.

I see that issue quite often in the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag realm, where OPs asking a plain c++ question and add tags like [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt), [clion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clion) or other fancy stuff, that actually doesn't have anything to do with the problem asked for.

I tend to remove these superfluous tags, so that the question will appear to the right audience.

---

<sub>I've also noticed, that some OPs try to *"hide"* under certain irrelevant tags, to avoid falling into the more general language *shark tank*</sub>

Comment: On the other hand, when people ask JavaScript questions, sometimes people tag for jQuery or some other utility library that they're using in order to signal that answers are aloud to include solutions from those libraries, even if the question isn't directly related to that library. Is that okay? Sometimes when asking it's not always possible to know which tags are relevant to the answer, because they don't know the answer.

Comment: @4castle: If the question isn't about jQuery, it shouldn't be tagged [tag:jquery], **but** the question should say that the OP is using jQuery so people know that they can use it in their solution. (And jQuery is so amazingly popular that they need to say clearly they're *not* using it if the question relates to JavaScript in the browser.) That said, it's a right mess and the [tag:jquery] tag is constantly misused, not least because often the person posting the question (and indeed people posting answers) have no clue what the distinction between jQuery and JavaScript is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree, but with other libraries like Underscore or Lodash, the question is often times answerable without the library, but the OP usually prefers the answer to use those libraries since it makes the code shorter if used effectively. I follow those tags because they tend to get answers that don't use the handy libraries, but if they didn't tag the library, I never would have found the question.

Comment: @4castle: Yes, if you're looking for an answer specifically using the lib, naturally you tag the lib. That's why I said "If the question isn't about jQuery."